# Hide certain warnings in Xamarin Studio

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Is there a way that I can hide certain warnings during a build in Xamarin Studio?  I have deliberately included certain class members in my solution that are deprecated and I am tired of being reminded every single time I compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right-click your project -> Options -> Build/Compiler and either adjust the warning level or list the warnings you don't want to be told about in the "Ignore warnings" text box.

Comment: note: The way to list the warnings you don't want to see is to put the numeric part of the warning code into the `Ignore warnings` field, e.g. if the warning code is CS0414, you put 414 in the field, separating codes with a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks. What code would you use for warning "MT4112"? i've tried both 112 and 4112 without results.

Comment: @Cadab, does putting MT4112 also not work?  If so I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: The MT warning codes do not come from the C# compiler, so those can't be hidden (only the CS warnings can).

Comment: @JasonHartley I didn't actually try the full code, but as Rofl has pointed out doesn't look like its possible.

Answer (score -1):

To see the Warning Code, click in `Errors` in the bottom right corner and in the end of the line of each warning you'll see it.
[image]